# Weird behavior when accessing RowDataPacket after a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, node-mysql

I have the following function to retrieve an sql row object.

```
function KnownConditionByUserFarm(d, callback) {
    var where = [
        d.user_hash,
        d.id,
        d.icon,
        d.days_since,
    ]

    sql = "SELECT id, NOW() as now, time, FROM_UNIXTIME(time), date_created, DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) as days_since FROM weathers WHERE user_hash = ? AND farm_id = ? AND icon = ? AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY));"

    query = db.query(sql, where, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err, null)
        } else {
            return callback(null, result)
        }

    });
}
```

I could retrieve it on my processor function and can do a console.log.

```
KnownConditionByUserFarm(data, (error, cond) => {

    if (error) {
        console.log("KnownConditionByUserFarm.Error:")
        console.log(error)
        process.exit()
    } else {

        console.log("KnownConditionByUserFarm/result")
        console.log(cond) // <-- can be accessed

    }
})
```

Result of `console.log(cond)`

```
KnownConditionByUserFarm/result
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 19,
    now: 2020-05-07T03:10:20.000Z,
    time: 1587772800,
    'FROM_UNIXTIME(time)': 2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z,
    date_created: 2020-04-24T22:16:13.000Z,
    days_since: 12 } ]
```

However, when I tried to access the rest of the object like `id`, `day_since`, I am receiving the following error.

> Code

```
console.log(cond[0].id)
```

> Error

```
KnownConditionByUserFarm/result
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 19,
    now: 2020-05-07T03:14:51.000Z,
    time: 1587772800,
    'FROM_UNIXTIME(time)': 2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z,
    date_created: 2020-04-24T22:16:13.000Z,
    days_since: 12 } ]
19 <-- I was able to access, but it's returning cannot read property.
KnownConditionByUserFarm/result
[]
***Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I was able to access the `id`, but it's throwing a weird `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`.

Note that I even tried to do a

```
var w = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cond))
console.log(w[0])
```

With the following result:

```
{ id: 19,
  now: '2020-05-07T03:22:24.000Z',
  time: 1587772800,
  'FROM_UNIXTIME(time)': '2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z',
  date_created: '2020-04-24T22:16:13.000Z',
  days_since: 12 }
```

When I accessed the `id`

```
console.log(w[0].id)
```

Result:

```
*/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what could be the cause of the issue I experienced, but I was able to resolve it by doing it again and logging carefully, until I got what I needed.

```
var w = JSON.stringify(cond[0])
console.log(w)

var p = JSON.parse(w)
console.log(p)

console.log(p.id)
console.log(p.days_since)

var ps = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cond[0]))
console.log(ps.days_since)
```